# How to get all ids in LINQ which two columns dont have predefined values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to retrieve all Ids from two columns, which doesnt contain some other list.
For example:
If I have a variable:

I need to select List of rows in All notifications by DeliveryTypeId and NotificationGroupId where those IDs not contained in pair combination in selected notifications.

```
var selectedNotifications = _dbContext.UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice.Include(m => m.NotificationGroup)
                            .Include(m => m.DeliveryType)
                            .Where(m => m.UserDefId == userDefId && m.UserTypeId == (int)userType)
                            .Select(m => new NotificationGroup()
                            {
                                NotificationGroupId = m.NotificationGroup.NotificationGroupId,
                                Name = m.NotificationGroup.Name,
                                DefaultDeliveryType = new DeliveryType()
                                {
                                    DeliveryTypeId = m.DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeId,
                                    Name = m.DeliveryType.Name,
                                    HasChoosen = true
                                }
                            }).ToList();

var selectedNotificationsMatchingIds = selectedNotifications.Select(n => new { n.NotificationGroupId, n.DefaultDeliveryType.DeliveryTypeId }).ToList();
```

and I need a condition witch will take all rows from db where is !contains.

example:

//NotificationGroup Codelist

```
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| NotificationGroupId |    Name     | DefaultDeliveryTypeId |
+=====================+=============+=======================+
| 1                   | Comments    | 1                     |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 2                   | QA          | 1                     |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 3                   | Services    | 1                     |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 4                   | eScheduling | 1                     |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 5                   | eDelivery   | 2                     |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

//Delivery Type Codelist

```
+----------------+-----------------+
| DeliveryTypeId |      Name       |
+================+=================+
| 1              | SMS             |
+----------------+-----------------+
| 2              | Email           |
+----------------+-----------------+
| 3              | PortalMessaging |
+----------------+-----------------+
```

//SELECTED NOTIFICATIONS

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
| UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoiceId | UserDefID | UserCompanyOrInstitutionId | NotificationGroupId | DeliveryTypeId | UserTypeId |
+======================================+===========+============================+=====================+================+============+
| 269                                  | 2933      | NULL                       | 1                   | 2              | 1          |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
| 270                                  | 2933      | NULL                       | 2                   | 2              | 1          |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
| 271                                  | 2933      | NULL                       | 3                   | 2              | 1          |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
| 272                                  | 2933      | NULL                       | 4                   | 2              | 1          |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
| 273                                  | 2933      | NULL                       | 4                   | 1              | 1          |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
```

//ALL NOTIIFICATIONS

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| NotificationGroupUserTypeId | NotificationGroupChangeTypeId | UserTypeId | NotificationGroupId | NotificationTemplateId |       DateCreated       | DeliveryTypeId |
+=============================+===============================+============+=====================+========================+=========================+================+
| 1                           | NULL                          | 1          | 1                   | 14                     | NULL                    | 1              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 6                           | 11                            | 1          | 4                   | 21                     | 2011-07-18 11:13:23.543 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 17                          | NULL                          | 1          | 4                   | 6                      | NULL                    | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 26                          | NULL                          | 1          | 3                   | 8                      | NULL                    | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 30                          | 11                            | 1          | 4                   | 15                     | 2011-07-17 13:16:36.897 | 1              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 31                          | 14                            | 1          | 4                   | 16                     | 2011-07-17 13:17:00.880 | 1              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 32                          | 15                            | 1          | 4                   | 17                     | 2011-07-17 13:17:18.220 | 1              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 33                          | 16                            | 1          | 4                   | 18                     | 2011-07-17 13:17:34.833 | 1              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 34                          | 17                            | 1          | 4                   | 19                     | 2011-07-17 13:17:58.337 | 1              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 35                          | 18                            | 1          | 4                   | 20                     | 2011-07-17 13:18:35.960 | 1              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 36                          | 14                            | 1          | 4                   | 22                     | 2011-07-18 16:00:27.320 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 37                          | 15                            | 1          | 4                   | 23                     | 2011-07-18 16:01:17.843 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 38                          | 16                            | 1          | 4                   | 24                     | 2011-07-18 16:01:36.300 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 39                          | 17                            | 1          | 4                   | 25                     | 2011-07-18 16:01:55.923 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 40                          | 18                            | 1          | 4                   | 26                     | 2011-07-18 16:02:12.607 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 41                          | 8                             | 1          | 3                   | 27                     | 2011-11-09 12:59:51.307 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 44                          | 19                            | 1          | 3                   | 28                     | 2011-12-21 14:57:31.780 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 48                          | 20                            | 1          | 5                   | 29                     | 2011-12-23 10:19:16.840 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| 49                          | 1                             | 1          | 3                   | 6                      | 2011-12-22 16:09:15.047 | 2              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

So I am getting in `selectedNotifications` correct pairs, but then when I try to filter my new query, I m getting only two pairs but I should get it (with these example):

```
var notSelectedNotifications = _dbContext.NotificationGroupUserType.Include(m => m.DeliveryType)
                                .Include(m => m.NotificationGroup)
                                .Where(m => m.UserTypeId == (int)userType)
                                .Where(m => !selectedNotificationsMatchingIds.Contains(new { m.NotificationGroup.NotificationGroupId, m.DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeId }))
                                .Select(m => new NotificationGroup()
                                {
                                    NotificationGroupId = m.NotificationGroupId,
                                    Name = m.NotificationGroup.Name,
                                    DefaultDeliveryType = new DeliveryType()
                                    {
                                        DeliveryTypeId = m.DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeId,
                                        Name = m.DeliveryType.Name,
                                        HasChoosen = false
                                    }
                                }).ToList();
```

Any advise is welcomed. If someone can tell me, how to get all of these which is not selected in `selectedNotificationsMatchingIds`

Comment: I've tried to edit the code sections to make them a little more legible.  It wasn't helpful that all but 2 lines were not visible on a normal-width page

Comment: The WHERE is wrong.  You want NOT and WHERE is giving EQUAL : .Where(m => m.UserDefId == userDefId && m.UserTypeId == (int)userType)

Comment: @jdweng but I put !Contains, I added negation.

Comment: First try with no WHERE and make sure you get results.  Then add WHEREs one at a time to  find issue.  There is something wrong with the logic and without the same database I will not be able to get a solution.  It is better you fix the logic error.

Answer (score 0):

The `Contains()` method usage default equality comparer when implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` is not provided for element stored in collection. Obviously the default equality comparer will not work for element of `Anonymous class`  stored in `selectedNotificationsMatchingIds`.

You have two options:

**Option 1:** Re-write `Where` condition to use `Any` as:

```
//.Where(m => !selectedNotificationsMatchingIds
//           .Contains(new { m.NotificationGroup.NotificationGroupId, 
//                                            m.DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeId }))

.Where(m => !selectedNotificationsMatchingIds
        .Any(c => c.NotificationGroup.NotificationGroupId == m.NotificationGroupId
                && c.DeliveryTypeId == m.DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeId))
```

**Option 2**: Create a class having properties for `NotificationGroupId` and `DeliveryTypeId` and implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface for it. Then only you can use object of that class as part of `.Contains()` method.